# Extracting text from a div with Jsoup

Tags: java, android, jsoup

With this code, the application should extract the text of the site div and display it on the screen , but that this did not occur and not [ and presented no error in Logcat , what am I doing wrong ?

```
    package com.androidbegin.jsouptutorial;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView txtdesc;

    // URL Address
    String url = "http://uat.sophiejuliete.com.br/tendencias/";
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Locate the Buttons in activity_main.xml
        Button titlebutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.titlebutton);
        txtdesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.desctxt);


        // Capture button click
        titlebutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // Execute Title AsyncTask
                new Title().execute();
            }
        });

    }


    private class Title extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Android Basic JSoup Tutorial");
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String desc = null;
            try {
                // Connect to the web site
                Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                // Using Elements to get the Meta data
                Elements description = document.select("div[class=postWrapper]");
                // Locate the content attribute
                desc = description.text();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return desc;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // Set description into TextView
            txtdesc.setText(result);
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }



}
```

This is the structure of the site you need to analyze :

```
<div class="postWrapper" id="post162">
        <div class="postTitle">


            <h2>
                <a href="http://uat.sophiejuliete.com.br/tendencias/agarradinhos-as-orelhas/">
                    Agarradinhos às orelhas                </a>
            </h2>

            <div class="fb-custom-share" data-url="http://uat.sophiejuliete.com.br/tendencias/agarradinhos-as-orelhas/">
                Compartilhar
            </div>

            <div class="date">
                26 de janeiro de 2015            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="postContent"><p>Agarradinhos às orelhas, os solitários e brincos curtos são ideais tanto para o dia como para a noite.</p>
<p>E melhor ainda ficam bem em qualquer formato de rosto.</p>
<p>Basta apenas escolher o modelo conforme a ocasião que você vai utilizar.</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><a href="http://sophiejuliete.com.br/shop/brincos.html"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://uat.sophiejuliete.com.br/media/wysiwyg/Agarradinhos_s_orelhas.jpg" alt=""></a></p></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
desc = description.text();
```

instead of

```
desc = description.attr("postContent");
```

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String url = "http://uat.sophiejuliete.com.br/tendencias/";
    Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(10000).get();
    // Using Elements to get the Meta data
    Elements description = document.select("div[class=postContent]");
    // Locate the content attribute
    String desc = description.text();
    System.out.println(desc);
    // prints out "Agarradinhos às orelhas, os solitários e brincos..."
}
```

**UPDATE**

Since the JSoup part is fixed, you probably have some issue with async task. Try using `String` as result type, something like this

```
private class Title extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    ...

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String desc = null;
        try {
            // Connect to the web site
            Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            // Using Elements to get the Meta data
            Elements description = document.select("div[class=postContent]");
            // Locate the content attribute
            desc = description.text();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return desc;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // Set description into TextView
        TextView txtdesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.desctxt);
        txtdesc.setText(result);
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

**UPDATE 2**

Declare `txtdesc` globally, in `MainActivity`

```
TextView txtdesc;
```

initialize it in `onCreate()`

```
txtdesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.desctxt);
```

and remove the declaration in `onPostExecute()`, so there is only `txtdesc.setText(result);`

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // Set description into TextView
    txtdesc.setText(result);
    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: I changed it
desc = description.attr ( " postContent " ) ;

that is why,
desc = description.text ();

And yet it did not work !

Comment: Works for me, maybe you have some other issues with your code but the JSoup part is fine. I've added a small example, can you check if it works for you?

Comment: I am newbie on the schedule, how and where I fit in this code snippet , you can position it on my posted code please ?

Comment: This is a sample demo method, doesn't have anything to do with the rest of your project. You can create a new class anywhere in the project and put this method in it (with necessary imports, of course) and run it. If you are using Eclipse IDE, just right click the class, and select `Run As -> Java Application` (similar for any other IDE). The resulting `desc` will be printed in the console.

Comment: Understood and performed the procedure and it worked fine , but my doubt still persists , because my project still does not work .

Comment: At least you know that now jsoup part is working. I've edited my answer, try modifying your `AsyncTask` accordingly

Comment: It did not work , he brings no data and not the error in logcat

Comment: I've made another edit, in case you already tried the previous one.

Comment: I'm about to give up, not even doing that it works and not of any error in logcat

Comment: Try to look for threads similar to this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23978400/how-to-update-ui-from-asynctask , I think that's where your problem is. Try to find a basic working demo, and build from there.