# Android setText unable to show string coming from the database

Tags: android

My application can select and show the data into the Log.e but it cannot set it into the textViews. What´s the reason for this?

I want to show the data just after an OnClick event, setting visibility to visible.

```
final TextView txv_yes = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.vou);
final TextView txv_no = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nao_vou);
final TextView txv_maybe = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.talvez);
show_count = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.show_block);

count_vou = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.count_vou);
count_nao = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.count_nao_vou);
count_talvez = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.count_talvez);

txv_yes.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    yes = txv_yes.getText().toString();
    new insertYes().execute();
    new select().execute();

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        setVisible();
                }
            });

    }
});

public class select extends AsyncTask<String, Boolean, Boolean>{

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("e_id", subString));

        try
        {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://website.com/includes/select_counter.php");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            inputStream = entity.getContent();
            Log.e("pass 1", "connection success ");
    }
        catch(Exception e)
    {
            Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid IP Address",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }     

        try
        {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
                (new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"UTF-8"));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
                inputStream.close();
                result = sb.toString();
            Log.e("pass 2", "connection success ");
    }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
    }     

    try
        {
            JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
            get_yes = (json_data.getString("Vou"));
            get_no = (json_data.getString("Nao_Vou"));
            get_maybe = (json_data.getString("Talvez"));
            Log.e("pass 3", "Vou : "+ get_yes);
            Log.e("pass 4", "Não Vou : "+ get_no);
            Log.e("pass 5", "Talvez: "+ get_maybe);

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
        }

        return null;
    }
}

public boolean setVisible() {
    show_count.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    count_vou.setText(get_yes);
    count_nao.setText(get_no);
    count_talvez.setText(get_yes);

    return true;

}
```

I had this block of code inside the try/catch jus after the Logs.e but the problem was the same:

```
count_vou.setText(get_yes);
count_nao.setText(get_no);
count_talvez.setText(get_yes);
```

Comment: My guess: `setVisible` is not in sync with your `AsyncTask`-s

Comment: Try putting `show_count.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` inside the try/catch along with the other `setText()` statements.

Comment: try to call setVisible method on Post Execute method of asynctask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**setVisible()** runs before the server call completes, and it's setting the values before you actually get the values.

So, instead of calling this code right after you trigger the async task, call in from within the async task, right after the Log statements. You can use the onPostExecute method of the async task.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        setVisible();
                }
            });

}
```

Comment: See also: [How to update ui from asynctask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23978400/how-to-update-ui-from-asynctask)

Comment: Great.. Thank you all for opening my eyes

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `this.count_vou.setText(get_yes);`  or `activityname.this.count_vou.setText(get_yes)`

It seems you are using in `runOnUI` thread and it doesn't getting access inside `runOnUi` method.

Answer (score 0):

setVisible() method call before your async task is completed. so you can not get database values in setVisible() method.

Implement onPostExecute method in your select asynctask then call setVisible() method inside it.

```
@Override
   protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
      setVisible();
   }
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**. Call setVisible() function after select asynctask finish. Remove Runnable thread

new select().execute(); 
        setVisible();

**Solution 2**. You can also call setVisible() in asynctask

@Override

```
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

    super.onPostExecute(result); 
    setVisible();

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:- Call setVisible() Method after assigning all values in AsyncTask.
 Code as below. Remove setVisible() method call from onClickListener

Try this below code.
Note :- You cannot change UI on background task. For that you have to add onPostExecute().

public class select extends AsyncTask{

```
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("e_id", subString));

    try
    {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://website.com/includes/select_counter.php");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        inputStream = entity.getContent();
        Log.e("pass 1", "connection success ");
}
    catch(Exception e)
{
        Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid IP Address",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}     

    try
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
            (new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"UTF-8"));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
            inputStream.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        Log.e("pass 2", "connection success ");
}
    catch(Exception e)
    {
    Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
}     

try
    {
        JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
        get_yes = (json_data.getString("Vou"));
        get_no = (json_data.getString("Nao_Vou"));
        get_maybe = (json_data.getString("Talvez"));
        Log.e("pass 3", "Vou : "+ get_yes);
        Log.e("pass 4", "Não Vou : "+ get_no);
        Log.e("pass 5", "Talvez: "+ get_maybe);

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
    }

    return null;
}
@Override


protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
  setVisible(); }}
```